# Reproducing InputManagerTest Buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

(Crosspost to Mixed Developer forums because they're still very inactive.)

Going through the HoloToolkit examples, I'm trying to reproduce the button input example in the InputManagerTest example for a GUI I'm making. Reproducing the button seems to cause a hiccup though. Here's what I do:

- I add a Canvas
- I add a Button to that Canvas

That's basically it. This looks very similar to the example. My scene, as well, as the InputManager, EventSystem, and Camera as instructed in the tutorial.

However, in the example, the button responds to Gaze, and hand click, which is what I want.

In my example, my button responds to my mouse and mouse click though. I also cannot change its color from the default.

Does anyone know why this all would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer my own question.  Standalone Input Module is automatically added as a component of the Event System in the current build.  This sets the default input to be the mouse cursor.  Disabling this component fixes the issue.